# Many to many relationship between two many to many relationships

Tags: c#, entity-framework, asp.net-core, database-design, entity-framework-core

I'm trying to model the following:

> We have a list of gyms, a list of clients and a list of plans.

> Each client can be assigned to multiple gyms, and of course a gym can have multiple clients.

> Each plan can be assigned to multiple gyms, and each gym can have multiple plans.

> However, clients and plans do not have a relationship outside a certain gym.

> Clients can be part of a gym without being assigned any plan, and plans can be part of a gym without being assigned any client.

This to me means that there is a N-N relationship between clients and gyms, and another N-N relationship between gyms and plans, however there is no N-N relationship between clients and plans.

So what I would need is like a ternary between `Clients`, `Gyms` and `Plans`, but forcing that the relationship between the `Client` and the `Gym` exists and also the relationship between the `Gym` and the `Plan` exists.

I started coding this:

```
public class Client
{
    [DatabaseGenerated(DatabaseGeneratedOption.Identity)]
    public string Id {get; set;}

    // other fields
    
    public virtual ICollection<Gym> Gyms {get; set;}
}

public class Gym
{
    [DatabaseGenerated(DatabaseGeneratedOption.Identity)]
    public string Id {get; set;}

    // other fields
 
    public virtual ICollection<Client> Clients {get; set;}
    public virtual ICollection<Plan> Plans {get; set;}
}

public class Plan
{
    [DatabaseGenerated(DatabaseGeneratedOption.Identity)]
    public string Id {get; set;}

    // other fields
    public ICollection<Gym> Gyms {get; set;}
}
```

But this gets even worse because I need another field in the relationship between `Gyms` and `Plans` so I made the corresponding intermediate class:

```
public class GymPlan
{
        [Key, Column( Order = 0 )]
        public string GymId { get; set; }

        [Key, Column( Order = 1 )]
        public string PlanId { get; set; }


        public virtual Gym Gym { get; set; }
        public virtual Plan Plan { get; set; }
        public int MyOtherProperty { get; set; }
}
```

And changed the `Plan` and `Gym` classes to reference this new intermediate table instead. However now I don't know how to proceed, I thought of doing the following but I believe it's wrong:

```
public class Client
{
    [DatabaseGenerated(DatabaseGeneratedOption.Identity)]
    public string Id {get; set;}

    // other fields
    
    public virtual ICollection<Gym> Gyms {get; set;}
    public virtual ICollection<GymPlan> GymPlans {get; set;}
}

public class GymPlan
{
        [Key, Column( Order = 0 )]
        public string GymId { get; set; }

        [Key, Column( Order = 1 )]
        public string PlanId { get; set; }


        public virtual Gym Gym { get; set; }
        public virtual Plan Plan { get; set; }
        public virtual ICollection<Client> Clients {get; set;}
        public int MyOtherProperty { get; set; }
}
```

EDIT: I tried it in a test project and it has this problem: if I delete a `Client`, all works well, but if I remove a `Client` from a `Gym`, the entry on the ternary is not removed, because it references `Client`, not the relationship between `Client` and `Gym`.

Tried to do the following:

```
public class Client
{
    [DatabaseGenerated(DatabaseGeneratedOption.Identity)]
    public string Id {get; set;}

    // other fields
    
    public virtual ICollection<GymClient> Gyms {get; set;}
}

public class Gym
{
    [DatabaseGenerated(DatabaseGeneratedOption.Identity)]
    public string Id {get; set;}

    // other fields
 
    public virtual ICollection<GymClient> Clients {get; set;}
    public virtual ICollection<GymPlan> Plans {get; set;}
}

public class Plan
{
    [DatabaseGenerated(DatabaseGeneratedOption.Identity)]
    public string Id {get; set;}

    // other fields
    public ICollection<GymPlan> Gyms {get; set;}
}

public class GymClient
{
        [Key, Column( Order = 0 )]
        public string GymId { get; set; }

        [Key, Column( Order = 1 )]
        public string ClientId { get; set; }


        public virtual Gym Gym { get; set; }
        public virtual Client Client { get; set; }

        public virtual ICollection<GymPlan> Plans {get; set;}
}

public class GymPlan
{
        [Key, Column( Order = 0 )]
        public string GymId { get; set; }

        [Key, Column( Order = 1 )]
        public string PlanId { get; set; }


        public virtual Gym Gym { get; set; }
        public virtual Plan Plan { get; set; }
        public virtual ICollection<GymClient> Clients {get; set;}

        public int MyOtherProperty { get; set; }
}
```

But that now is giving me an error because apparently adding the foreign keys with on delete cascade would cause cycles or multiple cascade paths. Anyone knows why?

Comment: It would be enough if you have many-to-many relationship between Client and GymPlan (and many-to-many between Gym and Plan), right? Through GymPlan you can extract all the gyms or plans client uses.

Comment: Let me try in a test project and come back to you real quick.

Comment: There is a problem with that, that way a client MUST have at least one plan in each gym right? So I don't get the N-N relationship between clients and gyms unless they also have at least one plan attached.

Comment: Could you edit you question and post what's required? What's the relationship between entities? Can client be part of a gym without plan? Etc.

Comment: Done, each entity can exist on their own, and clients DO NOT need to have any plans assigned in a gym, the same way plans DO NOT need to have any clients assigned in a gym. Thank you!

Comment: @StefanGolubović I modified the question again with some new things I tried and the errors it shows, can you check it out?

Comment: It's a difficult model, but I have one more question before I give up. Does a client have 0 or 1 plan in a gym, or can it have multiple (many) plans?

Comment: It's 0 to N, they can have no plans assigned, they can have 1 or they can have more.